# RTMP / RTSP (Flash Video Format) support for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, rtsp, rtmp, flv

I want to do real time streaming of data (in the form of video) which is in Flash Format, I searched and found out that apple do not give support to flash do we have any other third party
library which can be used,

After searching I found http://www.realtimelibs.com/#feature_3 but it is paid also I don't know weather it support flash format

I would love to get any help or any guidance

Comment: Thanks for the critic. Would you mind adding some comment why I got down-voted? AIR surely is an option, I doubt there are others

Comment: Lachlan.. What do you mean by "video is in Flash format"? Do you mean the media container is FLV or the video codec itself is [Adobe version of] H.263..?? iOS can only handle H.264 video and AAC/MP3 inside and MP4/M4A container. FLV can contain H.263 or H.264 and AAC or MP3 audio so its possible that you just need to move the Vid+Audio from FLV to MP4 containers to have a playable iOS file. I say move but really if you know programming it means replace any "FLV" part bytes with "MP4" structure ones and... voila! FLV is now MP4 playing on your iPhone.

Comment: PS: I dont code on iPhone, but I have played with FLV and MP4 bytes amongst others in AS3 so from knowledge thats what I'd do.. Write a player that receives FLV bytes, read bits, discard from memory and then create a new MP4 byte structure out of them and then tell the iOS to play the new byte buffer instead. MP4 aint fun though and you can tell its made by a commitee (MPEG). This only works if FLV has H.264 + AAC/MP3 in the first place. Also only if iPhone can handle byte juggling on-the-fly. This Muxing/Demux option is less intensive than a full format re-encode

Answer (score 0):

You might try to implement your app as an AIR app. AIR is the cross platform Flash runtime for iOS and Android.

Look for Apache Flex for a free Eclipse based IDE or use any of the Adobe tools.